# Reason Behind O(1) in finding the length of List in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I was going through https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity of Lists in python. I know python list internally works as an Array. But how internally length of list is `O(1)`. As it needs to traverse till end of list and increment the counter and return it.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: One can easily implement a list class having a member length which stores the actual length of the list, and whenever a request comes for its length, just return that member instead of finding the length again.

Comment: It keeps track of the length. It doesn't have to traverse the list to count it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR lists keep track of their length.

In CPython, calling `len([])` invokes the `Py_SIZE` C macro, which simply returns the value of the `ob_size` attribute.

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cda73a5af2ff064ca82140342b3158851d43868f/Objects/listobject.c#L438-L442

```
static Py_ssize_t
list_length(PyListObject *a)
{
    return Py_SIZE(a);
}
```

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9bdd2de84c1af55fbc006d3f892313623bd0195c/Include/object.h#L128

```cpp
#define Py_SIZE(ob) (_PyVarObject_CAST(ob)->ob_size)
```